# How to redirect the command ssh -V to a file?

Tags: bash, shell, redirect, ssh

I've tried tons of ways:

```
ssh -V > file.txt
ssh -V &> file.txt
ssh -V 2> file.txt
$(ssh -V) > file.txt
$(ssh -V) &> file.txt
file.txt <<< $(ssh -V)
```

And with shell substitution with variables as well. But every time the output is shown on screen.

Comment: `ssh -V &> file.txt` and `ssh -V 2> file.txt` should work, you can also try `ssh -V > file.txt 2>&1`

Comment: Hey, it worked with ssh -V > file.txt 2>&1. Thank you!

Comment: `&>` is Bash-specific but `ssh -V 2> file.txt` should work in all shells.